# Uglify File but don't minify certain strings

Tags: gulp, shopify, liquid, gulp-uglify, uglifyjs2

Is it possible using UglifyJS2 with gulp to effectivly ignore certain strings such as:

```
{% if VARIABLE == VARIABLE %}
{% else %}
{% elseif VARIABLE > VARIABLE %}
{% endif %}
```

Essentially, we are using liquid in our js as we are on the Shopify eCommerce platform. But we need the liquid to remain exactly how it is so that Shopify can process the liquid.

Many thanks for any help you can provide!